# Renaming files with double loop?

Tags: linux, bash

I have the below 28 files, where I would like to rename them to

```
1-1
1-2
...
7-1
7-4
```

plus the correct file extension. What I have tried it

```
for f in *; do
  for i in $(seq 7); do
    for j in $(seq 4); do
      mv $f $i-$j.${f#*.}
     done
   done
done
```

but this keeps renaming only the first file.

The order in which they are renamed doesn't really matter.

**Question**

Can anyone figure out how to rename the files, so they get the `$j-$i` naming?

```
0764342e9a7b64d67b13478443cc6657.png  43fd06b017043443817df07073d76447.png  933441d5176a82b2fdd17fcecb061f76.png
1769998f64f45708ab5660453a76bcd9.png  460c50f9498171d8b3b13415692ba744.png  9638e66b9c7ad1a958a12dcb19918e82.png
1f32eab75790c4ec79dfeeb363381351.jpg  4ba8abdc7e43864ec79d432e9c259ff5.png  9d28f3c61dca4daaecc7f257b4ee09be.jpg
237b4de6ee17bb5033d7b17660ceef75.png  5b09795f9eef920da1207b2549cd5d80.png  c1d0c1520d62a811f9de297eecc08235.png
288ac636a508b903ef1d5c8c914a531c.png  60eff92e2dcf2192449c47fdb94551a1.jpg  e2080072a8615f3016046f396ccba40f.png
2aeddcc1c52b32d81331c4be957bbfa4.png  6960cdb5cc9951e96f4a95aba44f9377.jpg  e2d25004b63c60f83b690d3394277d4d.jpg
2b9f5508623ef64f8f0e81ae6bb1fb24.png  6ab9951011bad2bed060658ac58ea7c1.png  e6989ec43b8fcab262b6a414313b6538.png
36f4a71039adaffdd3e173ab302e5142.png  6b0f52f96bce76c004be0a3d70e2ef3f.png  e8e7f53b39b632427333d700f34b2c5b.png
392da2e9809cca9d9357b3d1f4868de1.jpg  6c8a9665ee8a3e251bad53748815cedd.png
3e7bfa5919f5d49d3dfc27574f346337.png  8fd5ec47f3d31844be60c1350361905e.jpg
```

Comment: So, at each iteration you're trying to move the same file? Didn't you get any error?

Comment: No, each file should only be reanmed once.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could create an array containing the new prefixes and then loop over the filenames and fetch the corresponding array element.

```
# the convoluted way to create the array (don't use it, see below)
fnames=()
for i in {1..7}; do
  for j in {1..4}; do
     fnames+=("$i-$j")
  done
done

# the short way using two brace expansions, credits go to @Benjamin W.
fnames=({1..7}-{1..4})

idx=0
for f in *; do
  mv "$f" "${fnames[idx++]}.${f#*.}"
done
```

Comment: @Freddy Can you please explain how `${f#*.}` is printing the file extension?

Comment: @TheRockSays `${f#*.}` removes the shortest prefix of pattern `*.` from the filename, i.e. any characters followed by a `.`. If you had a filename `foo.txt`, it would remove `foo.` from the name. But if you had `foo.bar.txt`, then this would again only remove `foo.`. In this case you would need `${f##*.}` to remove the _longest_ prefix of the pattern to get the suffix `txt`. See [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)

Answer (score 2):

Creating two pseudo files, pasting them together and using sed to turn each line into a command:

```sh
paste <(printf '%s\n' *) <(printf '%s\n' {1..7}-{1..4}) \
    | sed 's/^/mv /;s/\(\....\)\(.*\)/\1\2\1/' \
    | bash
```

The output of the `paste` command is something like

```
$ paste <(printf '%s\n' *) <(printf '%s\n' {1..7}-{1..4})
0764342e9a7b64d67b13478443cc6657.png    1-1
1769998f64f45708ab5660453a76bcd9.png    1-2
1f32eab75790c4ec79dfeeb363381351.jpg    1-3
237b4de6ee17bb5033d7b17660ceef75.png    1-4
288ac636a508b903ef1d5c8c914a531c.png    2-1
2aeddcc1c52b32d81331c4be957bbfa4.png    2-2
2b9f5508623ef64f8f0e81ae6bb1fb24.png    2-3
36f4a71039adaffdd3e173ab302e5142.png    2-4
392da2e9809cca9d9357b3d1f4868de1.jpg    3-1
3e7bfa5919f5d49d3dfc27574f346337.png    3-2
<snip>
```

and so on; sed turns this into

```sh
mv 0764342e9a7b64d67b13478443cc6657.png 1-1.png
mv 1769998f64f45708ab5660453a76bcd9.png 1-2.png
mv 1f32eab75790c4ec79dfeeb363381351.jpg 1-3.jpg
mv 237b4de6ee17bb5033d7b17660ceef75.png 1-4.png
mv 288ac636a508b903ef1d5c8c914a531c.png 2-1.png
mv 2aeddcc1c52b32d81331c4be957bbfa4.png 2-2.png
mv 2b9f5508623ef64f8f0e81ae6bb1fb24.png 2-3.png
mv 36f4a71039adaffdd3e173ab302e5142.png 2-4.png
mv 392da2e9809cca9d9357b3d1f4868de1.jpg 3-1.jpg
mv 3e7bfa5919f5d49d3dfc27574f346337.png 3-2.png
<snip>
```

and piping to bash runs it.